# How to unblock cURL on ANY_XYZ_WEBSITE.com?

Tags: php, curl

I have a website that was grabbing data from "ANY_XYZ_WEBSITE.com."

I was using cURL to grab data automatically and then modifying it for my needs. But recently "ANY_XYZ_WEBSITE.com" has blocked all cURL requests and I am unable to grab data from their website. Is there any other way to get the data?

I am using PHP on IIS.

Comment: Does "ANY_XYZ_WEBSITE.com" happen to be "Kitco.com"? I can't tell if I'm missing something or if this is just a giant censorship fail. Anyway, it's their right to ban you for automating access to their site. Clearly they don't want you to do it.

Comment: Share your curl code.. .

Answer (score 2):

With all probability, they are blocking you based on the User-Agent header.

So --

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "SomethingElse/1.0");
```

before firing the request off.

If you want to masquerade as a real browser, http://www.user-agents.org/ is a comprehensive resource of different user-agents actually in current use.

But I'm seconding Polynomial's sentiment -- there's probably a reason for the site blocking cURL, so just don't be evil while requesting data from them.

Comment: Or maybe they blocked the OPs IP, but in that case there isnt anything he could do except asking them for permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the agent string. CURLOPT_USERAGENT

Answer (score 0):

1. **Never ever hit** in parallel / more than once on the same domain in an interval of **three seconds** atleast. If you can wait try to keep it atleast **ten** seconds.
2. Make sure your crawler read and follow robot.txt file before crawling a domain.

p,s,: Your curl has not been blocked, you have been blocked. And its not user_agent problem.

**What to do now?**

Have patience. Wait for a while. Refresh your IP (if dynamic) And hit again but following above two instructions. If still getting blocked, you need to specify your code and website you are talking about for a legal solution.